# How does make_pair deduce the types implicitly?

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair, template-argument-deduction

It is well known that `make_pair` deduces types. That is why it exists and it is convenient.
Now see this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/):

```
std::pair <int,int> foo;
std::pair <int,int> bar;

foo = std::make_pair (10,20);
bar = std::make_pair (10.5,'A'); //ok: implicit conversion from pair<double,char>
```

Now I want to understand when exactly the deduction takes place in the line above:

```
bar = std::make_pair (10.5,'A');
```

Does it create a pair then while assigning it implicitly casts `double` to `int` and `char` to `int`?

Comment: Have a look at [the assignment operator overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator%3D).

Comment: It **converts** the values; it does not **cast** anything. A cast is something that goes in source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It first creates a `std::pair<double, char>` thanks to type deduction of the helper function `std::make_pair` which creates a pair of **exactly the same** types than you passed to it, no matter to which type you later assign this pair to.

This object gets then assigned to a `std::pair<int,int>` which works thanks to a [templated assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator=). This operator basically allows assignable types (`U1` to `T1`, `U2` to `T2`) which internally assigns (in your case) a `double` to an `int` and a `char` to an `int`.

The language doesn't have a feature which "forecasts" the type of variable where the expression will be used, which would be required to make a `pair<int,int>` immediately without this step in between.

If you want to **avoid** that step you have to be explicit *when constructing* the pair, meaning that you shouldn't use the type deducting `std::make_pair` but rather `std::pair`'s constructor which requires you to put the explicit types. However, I doubt this will increase performance thanks to optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation!

Comment: Std::make_pair does not create a pair of "exactly the same" types you pass to it - std::make_pair *decays* the types passed to it, which can significantly transform the types (notably stripping const, which has just bitten me, argh. ).

Answer (score 4):

To elabourate on chris's comment, take a look at this

```
bar = std::make_pair (10.5,'A');
```

is the same as

```
std::pair <double,char> myPair = std::make_pair (10.5,'A'); 
bar = myPair;
```

This last line now uses the below assignment operator

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair& operator=( const pair<U1,U2>& other );
```

> Assigns other.first to first and other.second to second

Thus pairs of any type are assignable to each other, as long as the underlying types are assignable.